# Access Polymer inner element programmatically

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm enclosing my app in a Polymer element and I want to use another polymer element inside it. To call all the method of the inner element I'm trying to use $[]. 
Insider the external polymer element I have this:

```dart
ImageEditor ime;
DivElement div2;
ImageTool.created(): super.created(){
  div2 = $["secondDiv"];
  ime = $["imageEditor1"]
}
```

In the Html I simply have:

```dart
<polymer-element name="da-imagetool">
<template>
<div class="images" id="mainDiv">
  <da-imageeditor id="imageEditor1" name="ied"></da-imageeditor>
```

with the script src at the end.
For some reason I get an exception when I assign the imageEditor1 to ime.

> Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'ImageEditor' of 'value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the browser hasn't upgraded the `<da-imageeditor>` elements.

Make sure that you `<import>` the `<da-imageeditor>` element, and have the correct `@CustomTag` annotation on the `ImageEditor` class declaration.

Comment: It was indeed so banal. I forgot an e in the import.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with the import path.
If you don't use the right path the type is not recognized (canonicalization problem)

This bug should be solved since a while 
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15953
but I haven't worked with Polymer since.

Show your import paths (HTML and Dart) and the directory structure of your app (where is your entry page and your Polymer elements) then I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks but it was more banal :/

Answer (score 0):

Which version of dart-polymer are you using? With the 0.9.5, the following lines:

```dart
XElement.created(): super.created() { print($['el-id']); }

void enteredView() { print($['el-id']); }
```

In created(), the referred element gives nothing whereas in enteredView(), it does refer to the specific element of the shadow root.

The behavior disappears if `shadowRoot.querySelector('#el-id')` is used in lieu of the shorthand map `$['el-id']`.

Comment: This is not really odd. The element has to be initialized and 'upgraded'. There are some lifecycle callbacks like `ready` and `enteredView` where this is already done. `$['el-id']` doesn't work in the constructor because the collection is not yet filled with the references to its children but in `enteredView` this was already done. `shadowRoot.querySelector` does the children lookup itself so it doesn't depend on this to be finished.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Let's nail that 'odd' qualitative. After all, it is a bit over the top as such a behavior was completely conceivable.

Comment: Documentation could be better but would be able to maintain it when things are just evolving and changing continually and fast.